# CorelDRAW X8: How to increase the number of colors in my color palette?

Tags: color, corel-draw, palette

I really need more colors to pick from. Right now I use the color hue cube to get more colors. I was wondering if there's any way to increase the number of colors/add more colors in the RGB palette itself?

[image: The color palette in CorelDRAW X8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't edit the default palettes in Corel Draw, you will have to (tediously) make one.

If you go to Window>Colour Palettes>Palette Editor you add colours and then save the palette.

To access that palette, save it in a location where it won't be disturbed, like Documents.

Then go to Window>Colour Palettes>Open Palette... and navigate to the palette you've created. You can then continue to add to this as you please, saving it each time.

You can also long press a colour and it will give you a fly out that shows light to dark variations of the that colour.